# dynamic substring in c#

Tags: c#, substring

I have a set of code in c# I want to store into the database what the user is entering in the textbox.

The user enters into the textbox like this

```
input namexyzpan9837663placeofbirthmumbailocationwadala
```

This is what user enters

> (name: xyz pan: 9837663 place of birth: mumbai location: wadala)

Output into the database

> xyz 9837663 mumbai wadala

OR

> name xyzapan72placeofbirthgoalocationpanji
>
> (> name: xyza pan: 72 place of birth: goa location: panji)

Output into the database

> xyza 72 goa panji

name, age, location and placeofbirth are static but the value inside
them are dynamic

I know substring is helpfull but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: name, pan and place of birth is static?

Comment: name pan placeofbirth and location are always static for everyuser

Comment: Your question is not well formed. Please check this: [ask] to find out how it should be formulated. What have you tried till now? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @MaciejLos sir i want to create an web app in which user will enter his detail in a single textbox and with the help of the string all his information will be entered into the database

Comment: You need seperator. It is not good input.

Comment: I am not the user I am A developer I cant say to every user to do a good input they can give the information in any format

Comment: Better contain your user by using 4 text boxes, each for one field.

Comment: the client want only one textbox

Comment: It is wired that your user wishes to type such unreadable text instead of 4 well placed text boxes. If you want to anyway entertain your user's bad habit, learn to use Regex and keep suffering as a developer without bargaining power.

Comment: @Tommy I asked my user about multiple textboxes but he want to use single textbox and don't want to make the website more heavy with multiple textbox and different functionality and if you are working somewhere you will understand how client demandes

Answer (score 3):

Use can use `Split` if the keywords are static :

```
string strMain = "namexyzpan9837663placeofbirthmumbailocationwadala";

var results = strMain.Split(new string[] { "name", "pan", "placeofbirth", "location" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string name = results[0];
string pan = results[1];
string location = results[2];
```

You said you didn't know how to use `Substring`, well here it is working:

**Note that the second parameter for this method is the length of the string to be taken and not the index at which to stop.**

```
string strMain = "namexyzpan9837663placeofbirthmumbailocationwadala";

int indexOfName = strMain.IndexOf("name");
int indexOfPan = strMain.IndexOf("pan");
int indexOfBirth = strMain.IndexOf("placeofbirth");
int indexOflocation = strMain.IndexOf("location");

int effectiveIndexOfName = indexOfName + "name".Length;
int effectiveIndexOfPan = indexOfPan + "pan".Length;
int effectiveIndexOfBirth = indexOfBirth + "placeofbirth".Length;
int effectiveIndexOflocation = indexOflocation + "location".Length;

string name1 = strMain.Substring(effectiveIndexOfName, indexOfPan- effectiveIndexOfName);
string pan1 = strMain.Substring(effectiveIndexOfPan, indexOfBirth - effectiveIndexOfPan);
string birth1 = strMain.Substring(effectiveIndexOfBirth, indexOflocation - effectiveIndexOfBirth);
string location1 = strMain.Substring(effectiveIndexOflocation);
```

`namenamepan9837663placeofbirthmumbailocationwadala` works using the second method. But `namepanpan9837663placeofbirthmumbailocationwadala` is an interesting case that definitely needs a workaround.

Comment: namenamepan9837663placeofbirthmumbailocationwadala?

Comment: namexyzpan9837663placeofbirthmumbailocationwadala  

THIS IS DYNAMIC

Comment: not working it is always printing this 

xyz 9837663 mumbai wadala

Comment: @MumbaiWadala What string are you testing with ?

Comment: `string strMain = "namexyzpan9837663placeofbirthmumbailocationwadala";
int indexOfName = strMain.IndexOf("name");
int effectiveIndexOfName = indexOfName + "name".Length;
string name1 = strMain.Substring(effectiveIndexOfName, effectiveIndexOfPan - effectiveIndexOfName);
Label1.Text = name1.ToString();`

this is how i tested it

Comment: @MumbaiWadala Fixed. Check it now.

Comment: still the output is same

Comment: @MumbaiWadala What is the wrong output and what is the correct one ? I'm getting the correct output on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is designed for such case.

```
var input = @"namexyzpan9837663placeofbirthmumbailocationwadala";

var match = Regex.Match(input, @"^\s*"
    + @"name\s*(?<name>\w+?)\s*"
    + @"pan\s*(?<pan>\w+?)\s*"
    + @"placeofbirth\s*(?<placeOfBirth>\w+?)\s*"
    + @"location\s*(?<location>\w+)\s*" + @"$");

var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
var pan = match.Groups["pan"].Value;
var placeOfBirth = match.Groups["placeOfBirth"].Value;
var location = match.Groups["location"].Value;
```

Comment: what does this mean?

@"name\s*(?<name>\w+?)\s*"

Comment: It is 'Regular Expression' which allows you matching any patterns. '\s*' means any spaces, '\w+?' means any words. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Hebele check the below method using `Substring`.

Comment: Because "location" is not included. Do you want to accept text with some field missed?

Comment: Be careful. That is place of birth.

Comment: @Tommy I know. I want to show you that keys (name, pan..) can be value also. name: name pan: pan..

Comment: xyz 9837663 mumbai wadala

it is printing this

Comment: @Hebele, this `namenamepanpanplaceofbirthplaceofbirthlocationlocation` is splited very well, even if keys are used as a values. There's only one requirement: all keys have to be inserted into string.